How to show that a unit ball in $C^{s}([a,b])$ is relatively compact in $C^{r}([a,b])$
I'm having a difficult time proving that, if $0<r<s<1$, then the closed unit ball of $C^{s}([a,b])$ is compact in $C^{r}([a,b])$. Here, $C^{\alpha}([a,b])$ denotes Hölder space with exponent $\alpha$, equipped with the following norm:
$$||f||_{C^{\alpha}} = \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)| + \sup_{x,y\in[a,b], x\ne y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$$
I've succeeded in proving that the former set is contained in the latter. My strategy for proving compactness involves proving that the unit ball is equicontinuous in $C^{r}([a,b])$ with respect to the norm of that space. However, the above norm is very unwieldy, and I'm having a hard time "reducing" my problem to considering the functions with respect to a simpler norm, like the uniform norm. Any hints or tips would be appreciated, and let me know if I can clarify anything. :)
P.S.: In case it would be helpful, here is an explicit description of the unit ball in $C^{s}([a,b])$:
$$\{f \in C^{r}([a,b]) : ||f||_{C^{s}} \leq 1\}$$

Check the proof of Arzela-Ascoli. The convergent subsequence follow from the same method.

There is a proof in Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition . See the section titled: Compact embedding of Hölder spaces.
